# I'm parsing an HTML using lxml, but I only want a small subset of tags. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, lxml

I'd prefer not to build the entire tree in memory and just pick the elements I'm looking for.

Comment: High-performance XML parsing in Python with lxml http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/

Answer (score 0):

You could always use [PyQuery](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/css.html); a JQuery like library for quick xml and xhtml manipulation.